# Integrate buildroot with BeagleBone github repository

Tags: linux, git, github, beagleboneblack, buildroot

I am using Buildroot to produce root filesystem and kernel for my BeagleBone Black. Currently I provide my custom kernel to buildroot. But I noticed there is several ready-made kernels for BeagleBone Black on [GitHub](https://github.com/beagleboard/linux).

Since Buildroot allows to download kernel source directly from a git repository, I should be able just to point Buildroot to the BeagleBone's kernel repository on GitHub and Buildroot should download and compile the kernel for me.

Unfortunately the things are not so easy. When I specify BeagleBone's kernel repository in Buildroot, the kernel source is successfully cloned, but there is no default configuration and maybe some patch work is also necessary.

Did anybody try to integrate Buildroot with BeagleBone's GitHub's kernel sources?

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use the `beaglebone_defconfig` configuration provided by Buildroot. It uses a 4.4 kernel for the BeagleBone, fetched from git://git.ti.com/processor-sdk/processor-sdk-linux.git.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. I made some research about various available kernel repositories and it seems the BeagleBone's GitHub repository is a fork of TI's repository, but focused to just BeagleBone and all capes available for it. So I still prefer the GitHub repository.